# Programmatically stopping Solr Indexing

Tags: solr

We are programmatically creating items and using Solr indexes so we want to disable solr indexing whenever we create an item.

We tried following code to disable during item creation `Item.Add()`

```
Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Indexing.Enabled = false;
```

But it does not stop indexing and still happen in Solr. What can be the possible reason?

Answer (score 6):

Code which you have used, it works only for "old" indexes, but not for the Sitecore 7 indexes. I am sure you must be using old one.

You should try to disable/enable indexing as follows

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexCustodian.PauseIndexing();
// Add code to create item
IndexCustodian.ResumeIndexing();
```

Also add check whether indexing is currently paused or not with the use of the following:

```
IndexCustodian.IsIndexingPaused(ISearchIndex index )
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the complete namespace of the IndexCustodian - I was struggeling to find it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do in next way :

```
IndexCustodian.PauseIndexing();
  // Create items, etc 
  // Enable indexing again. 
IndexCustodian.ResumeIndexing();
```

Comment: Also you can use new BulkUpdateContext() & EventDisabler() which would hold indexing & events to manage performance while creating/editing item programmtically.  More details here   https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/silently-create-item-create-item-without-triggering-indexing-or-other-events