# Save Item Rule - Inserting item causes recursion

Tags: rules-engine, branch

I am using the rule engine to insert a branch template under an item on Item Save. The problem is that each item in the branch subsequently triggers Item Save. Is there a way to prevent the branch from triggering the rule? Or excluding the branch from the rule? Its making Item Save take forever.

**UPDATE**

Here is what the rule is actually doing:

1. Is the item content (Checks path)
2. Does the item inherit from a template
3. The item does not already have the branch as a child

If all are true, insert the branch

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107457/discussion-on-question-by-ethan-schofer-save-item-rule-inserting-item-causes-r).

Comment: In your save event code, you need to disable the execution of events. See samples on using the `EventDisabler` here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/silently-create-item-create-item-without-triggering-indexing-or-other-events

Comment: I have already tested and confirmed that this is not true. Even with Event Disabler, all items in the branch trigger Item Save.